# Does Trespasser il-vec still deal damage after giving itself Shadow?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

**Scenario**

1. I attack with a 4/4 beast token
2. My opponent chooses to block with [Trespasser il-Vec](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrespasser%20il-Vec%5d)
3. After declaring blocker, my opponent uses Trespasser's ability to discard [Fiery Temper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFiery%20Temper%5d) and pay madness cost to deal 3 damage to my beast creature.

Does Trespasser still deal his combat damage to my beast token, even though he now has shadow and is an illegal blocker?

Comment: Not sure if it's quite a duplicate: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21067/if-a-creature-loses-flying-after-blockers-are-declared-is-the-block-still-legal

Comment: Also: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/what-happens-if-a-blocking-creature-with-flying-loses-flying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Trespasser still deals combat damage.

The relevant passage is in [comprehensive rules 509.1b](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Declare_blockers_step) (emphasis mine):

> A restriction may be created by an evasion ability (a static ability
>   an attacking creature has that restricts what can block it). **If an
>   attacking creature gains or loses an evasion ability after a legal
>   block has been declared, it doesn’t affect that block.** Different
>   evasion abilities are cumulative.

Comment: Hmm, it's unfortunate that the rules quote say "an attacking creature", because in this case the attacking creature isn't the one that changed, the blocking creature was. The answer is still correct, of course. I don't see a different rule that makes it clearer.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the beast token does kill the Trespasser in this scenario.

Comment: There is not a specific rule that addresses this. In this case, it's the order of the rules that matters. The defending player checks restrictions and requirements in 509.1 (subrules 509.1b and 509.1c). Neither player gets priority until 509.4. Rules aren't normally ordered, but rules 509.1-4 are, because they are written like "First", "Second", etc. So at the exact moment when the check is made, the blockers are legal, and it doesn't matter what happens after that.

Comment: @GendoIkari usually it's an attacker that would change to evade, though they have to do it in declare attackers or earlier due to this rule, the rule does specify attacking for another reason, shadow is the only evasion ability that prevents a block, flying can block non flying, unblockable can block as normal, landwalk can still block, etc.